# When using textFile to create an RDD in Spark, what is the index that is displayed in the result?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

When I create an RDD using `sc.textFile` in Spark, I get a result like:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///home/cloudera/data MapPartitionsRDD[133] at textFile at <console>:23
```

What does the `[133]` represent? I see that it increases, so feels like some kind of ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looking at the implementation of RDD, its the ID of the RDD that will be used to identify the RDD uniquely within the SparkContext,

See below the toString() method of RDD where the **id** gets included along with the creation site.

```
override def toString: String = "%s%s[%d] at %s".format(
    Option(name).map(_ + " ").getOrElse(""), getClass.getSimpleName, id, getCreationSite)
```